# PHPMailer -- "Less secure" SMTP or PHP's mail() function?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a "lesser of two evils" quandary.  The site I'm working on doesn't have SSL.  So, I'm getting the SMTP issues described here: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#php-56-certificate-verification-failure

So, the options seem to be...

1. Using the php `mail()` function via PHPMailer by NOT using the built-in `$mail->isSMTP();` part of PHPMailer.
2. Going with the "less secure way" of sending SMTP mail as described in the link above.

Can someone who knows about this sort of thing weigh in with pros/cons of either route?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two are not the only options. Figure out *why* the certificate is failing to verify using the tests shown in the guide.

PHPMailer will use encryption if either a) you ask it to, or b) if your server *says* it supports it, in which case it's enabled automatically.

If your server is presenting a self-signed or expired cert, it will fail to verify - you can either get a real cert, tell your mail server to stop advertising encryption if it's not configured, or tell PHPMailer not to use encryption at all by setting `SMTPSecure = false` and `SMTPAutoTLS = false`.

Not using `isSMTP` isn't any more secure - all that happens is the same connection happens from your local mail server, where it may (depending on your mail server's settings) face exactly the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I've been waiting to post a comment until I had my SSL set up.  I finally have a new SSL cert. on my site and I'm getting the same error.  Specifically, it says "Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`*.example.com' did not match expected CN=`mail.example.com' in /path/to/phpmailer/class.smtp.php on line 353"  Does that specifically point to anything?